# SQL SELECT from one of two columns where column value is not equal to something

Tags: sql, sql-server

if I have a table with two columns, and the value for one of them will be known, is there a way to SELECT the value that is not equal to the known value and cast it as another column name?

For instance

```
columna       columnb
1             5
3             1
4             1
1             7
```

I want to query both columns in the table above for all values not equal to 1, and return the list in a single column called `column` (or similar), i.e. the resultant table should be:

```
column
3
4
5
7
```

Comment: What is the known value?  What results would you want?

Comment: Hi Gordon, I want to query the table above for all values not equal to 1, so if any value in columna or columnb is not one, I'd like it returned, in a table with a single column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want:

```
select distinct col
from t cross join
     (values (columna), (columnb)) v(col)
where col <> 1;
```

This will capture situations where both columns are not "1".

If your intention is something along the lines of "the other talker" in a chat, then:

```
select t.*, (case when columna <> 1 then columna else columnb end) as col
from t
where 1 in (columna, columnb);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for:

- [Field alias.](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp)
- [`Where` clause](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp).

Your query:

```
SELECT 
       columnb as [column]  --here the alias
FROM 
       yourTable
WHERE 
       columnb <> 1 or columnea <>1   --here the where clause
```

Notice: you can use `and` or `or` operator in `where` clause.

Quoting [t-sql select docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> *column_ alias*
>   Is an alternative name to replace the column name in the query result set. For example, an alias such as Quantity, or Quantity to Date, or Qty can be specified for a column named quantity.
>   Aliases are used also to specify names for the results of expressions, for example:
>
> `SELECT AVG(UnitPrice) AS [Average Price]`
>      `FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail;`

**Edited** due to OP comments:

To get values from both columns, the easiest way for you is a [UNION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
SELECT 
       columnb as [column]  --here the alias
FROM 
       yourTable
WHERE 
       columnb <> 1         --here the where clause
UNION ALL
SELECT 
       columna as [column]  --here the alias
FROM 
       yourTable
WHERE 
       columna <> 1         --here the where clause
```

Comment: I need it to return only one column

Comment: OK, one column now.

Comment: Sorry dani I might not have been clear - the value I want could be in either columna or columnb, and I need that value, whether it resides in either column.  This answer only checks columnb

Comment: that only returns values from columnb

Comment: ok, do you need two values in just one column? This is not possible on SQL. May be concatenating?

Comment: Hi, I only need one of the two values, but the value could be in either column

Comment: thanks; please provide a working example and i'll accept as answer :)